# Rest API Test Class

Tags: unit-test, rest-api

I have been looking at some material in relation to Rest API test classes but I am getting a bit lost/confused. Can some one help me with the following?

I have a class that looks something like this:

```
Global class AccountToFACustomer{ 

    Global class Response {
    public integer code {get; set;}
    public String body {get; set;}
    public boolean success {get; set;}
    public string errorText {get; set;}

     Response (integer code, String body){
            this.code = code;
            this.body = body;
            this.success = (code == 200 || code == 201);
    }
}

public class CustomerResponse{     
    public string uuid {get; set;}
    public Location location {get; set;}
}

public class Location {
   public string uuid {get; set;}
}

 webservice static Response CreateCustomer(id accountId){

    Response resp;
    Account a;

     a= [SELECT XYZ, ABC  FROM Account WHERE Id = :accountId];  

        JSONGenerator gen = JSON.createGenerator(true);
        ....
        gen.close();
        String jsonString = gen.getAsString();

        string token = 'Token XXX';

        HttpRequest req = new HttpRequest();
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        Http h = new http();

        req.setHeader('Authorization', token);
        req.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        req.setHeader('Accept-Type', 'application/json');

        string endpoint = 'https://api.test.net/customer/';
        string method = 'POST';
        req.setMethod(method);
        req.setEndpoint(endpoint);
        req.setBody(jsonString);
        res = h.send(req);
        resp = new Response(res.getStatusCode(), res.getBody());     

        CustomerResponse custresp =  (CustomerResponse)JSON.deserialize(res.getBody(), CustomerResponse.class);

        a.FieldAwareID__c = custresp.uuid; 
        a.Sync_to_FieldAware__c = 'Synced :'+system.now();
        a.LocationUUID__c = custresp.Location.uuid;

        update a;
        }
        }
```

and after reading some documentation on Test classes I have:

```
@isTest

global with sharing class TestFAConnectorClasses { 

 static testmethod void testCustomerCallout() {

     Account a = new account(Name='Test', Sage_ID__c='33',
                             Email__c='denis@test.com', Phone='3424123',
                             website='www.test.com', alpha__c='TST', 
                             VAT_No__c ='7896978', CurrencyIsoCode='GBP',
                             BillingStreet='Street', BillingCity='City',
                             BillingState='State', BillingCountry='Ireland'
                            );
     a.RecordTypeId = [select id from recordtype where name='CrossRefNI Account' and sobjectType='Account'].id;

     insert a;

     Test.setMock(HttpCalloutMock.class, new MockHttpResponseCustomerGenerator());
     AccountToFACustomer.CreateCustomer(a.Id);
     }
 }
```

and

```
@isTest

global class MockHttpResponseCustomerGenerator implements HttpCalloutMock {

    global HTTPResponse respond(HTTPRequest req) {

        System.assertEquals('https://api.test.net/customer/', req.getEndpoint());
        System.assertEquals('POST', req.getMethod());

        // Create a fake response
        HttpResponse res = new HttpResponse();
        res.setHeader('Content-Type', 'application/json');
        res.setBody('{"uuid":"798678697867697", "location": {"uuid": "465465489654"}}');
        res.setStatusCode(200);
        return res;
    }
}
```

Can someone help point me in the right direction?

Comment: Your missing the test.startTest and stopTest methods

Comment: I just added them in but the test is still failing, I'm getting this error: System.CalloutException: You have uncommitted work pending. Please commit or rollback before calling out

Comment: Do a search on that error plenty of info out there about it

Comment: Place Test.startTest() before Test.setMock() and follow it with Test.stopTest(). Performing a DML statement and a callout within the same transaction may be causing you this issue. If you are performing a DML I would suggest moving your callout to a seperate method and mark it with the @future annotation.